# Net core 2 map product have multi attributes in result SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, asp.net-core

My problems went I call a stored procedure and it returns results.

Example:

```
Declare @Tbl_Product Table 
                     (
                        [Code] int,
                        [Name] nvarchar(250),
                        [NameAttribute] nvarchar(250), 
                        [ValueAttribute] nvarchar(250)
                     )

Insert Into @Tbl_Product ([Code], [Name], [NameAttribute], [ValueAttribute])
values ('1', 'Nike', 'Color', 'Red'),
       ('1', 'Nike', 'Color', 'Blue'),
       ('1', 'Nike', 'Size', '10'),
       ('2', 'Addidas', 'Size', '10')
```

I have a class in C# (on .net Core 2) to fetch data from SQL Server:

```
public class Product
{   
        public string Code {get;set}
        public string Name {get;set}
        public List<Attribute> Attributies  {get;set}
}

public class Attribute
{
    public string NameAttribute {get;set}
    public string ValueAttribute {get;set}
}
```

I call a stored procedure and get a result set.

How to map this data to my `Product > Attributes` classes?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your stored procedure look like? What *shape* is the data being returned by it? Without that information, no one will be able to really help you at all...

Comment: Also, what ORM are you using?

Comment: @marc_s: we call storeA and result return: Select * from Tbl_Product
In Tbl_Product, We have 2 columns: NameAttribute , ValueAttribute
How should We input it in to property of Product: Attributies  ? (in .net Core)

Comment: @Zohar Peled: current, I use DbContext to Exec SQL Store Procedure and receive data. Parse it to Object.
var rSQL = await _repo.RawQueryMultipleAsync<ProductDTO>($"EXEC [dbo].[proc_GetProducts] Company = '{request.Company}' , ConditionParameters='{jsonCondition}' " );

Currently, I auto parse to Code & Name. but Attributies  is null.